# Searching for Active Directory User using SID across multiple sub-domains

Tags: powershell, active-directory

For a given Active Directory forest (let's call it forest1), I do have multiple sub domains (domain1, domain2, etc.).

The users that are in my application can have an account created on each of these domains (with the same cn, but a unique userPrincipalName).

When the first account is created, I store the objectSid of this account so I can use it for a lifetime.

In one of my PowerShell scripts, I would like to use the objectSid as a filter across forest1 in order to retrieve the first account created.

When I run the following script for a user for which `cn=test`, I am getting

> Cannot find an object with Identity 'test' in DC=forest1,DC=com

```
$forest = (Get-ADDomainController -DomainName \'forest1.local\' -Discover).Hostname;
$pw = ConvertTo-SecureString '${password}' -AsPlainText -Force;
$mycred = New-Object -Typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 'forest1\ServiceAccountUser',$pw;
$User = Get-ADUser -Identity '${user.username}' -Server $forest -Credential $mycred -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        Where-Object -Property SID -like '${user.firstSid}';
```

If I target one of the sub domains as below, it works fine:

```
$domain = (Get-ADDomainController -DomainName \'domain1.forest1.local\' -Discover).Hostname;
$pw = ConvertTo-SecureString '${password}' -AsPlainText -Force;
$mycred = New-Object -Typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 'forest1\ServiceAccountUser',$pw;
$User = Get-ADUser -Identity '${user.username}' -Server $domain -Credential $mycred -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        Where-Object -Property SID -like '${user.firstSid}';
```

Therefore I would like some help on:

- How can we specify in the script to browse all the sub domains in the `Get-ADUser`?
- If the account is deleted, can we still make this script working?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following:

```
$domains = Get-ADForest | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Domains
$SID = 'some sid value'
$CN = 'user CN'
foreach ($domain in $domains) {
    $DC = (Get-ADDomainController -DomainName $domain -Discover).Hostname
    $User = Get-ADObject -filter "CN -eq '$CN' -and ObjectSID -eq '$SID'" -Server $DC -IncludeDeletedObjects -Credential $mycred -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

**Explanation:**

- You can list all of your subdomains using the [Get-ADForest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adforest?view=win10-ps) command, and that collection is stored in `$domains`.
- A `foreach` loop can loop through each of those domains with the current domain being `$domain`.
- For each domain, you can query for a domain controller to store in `$DC` and then perform a `Get-ADObject` with the `-IncludeDeletedObjects`.
- To speed up your query, you can use the `-filter` switch rather than piping to `Where-Object`.
- You can filter on the `CN` and `ObjectSID` attributes.

---

**Additional Considerations:**

In this script, nothing is being done with the discovered data. I am not sure where you want to go from here. You will need to add some other logic like an `if` statement to check the value of `$User`. Because we are using `-filter`, `$user` will be `$null` if no object is found rather than throwing an error, which you will see when using `Get-ADObject -Identity`. From there you can do additional processing even if that means utilizing `break` statements.

```
if ($user) {
    # User was found. Process code here.
    break # Exit the foreach loop because further loop processing is not needed
}
else {
    # User was not found. Process code here
}
```

No output is generated in the solution because all queried data is stored in variables. The value of `$DC` and `$User` will be overwritten during each loop iteration. It may be best to store the discovered user data in a collection with a specific set of properties. You could retrieve `DistinguishedName` or `CanonicalName` along with `SamAccountName` and `ObjectSID` to know which domain and container has the user object.

```
$Users = foreach ($domain in $domains) {
    $DC = (Get-ADDomainController -DomainName $domain -Discover).Hostname
    Get-ADObject -filter "CN -eq '$CN' -and ObjectSID -eq '$SID'" -Server $DC -IncludeDeletedObjects -Properties CanonicalName,SamAccountName,ObjectSID -Credential $mycred -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        Select-Object SamAccountName,ObjectSID,CanonicalName
}
```

In the code snippet above, `$users` will now contain a collection of found users with the `SamAccountName`,`ObjectSID`,`CanonicalName` properties for each object.

Like [Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps), [Get-ADObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adobject?view=win10-ps) has a limited set of default display properties. You will need to use the `-Properties` parameter to display what you require. You can test what is available by starting with `-Properties *`.

Not much information has been provided on how AD user data is being input into the script. You may have a collection of `CN` values or CSV file. You will have to consider how to iterate over those values.

Comment: Thank for the given advices. I will update this answer once it is successful. The objective behind that is to add this specific user a group on a trusted forest, where it uses the SID of the first account created.

Comment: As mentioned below, your suggestions **works** as I was able to retrieve the correct user, using tweaks in the logs. However, i am getting an exception related to executing to much requests on all domains instead of using global catalog.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but you can call the WMI Win32_SID class with the SID =  as parameter. Works for me with two-way trusts.